# RaphaelJS scale issue

Tags: svg, resize, raphael, transform, scale

Can someone help me on this? I tried to shrink the size of the svg to half of its original size.

```
Here is the JSfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/wildleaf/ntzf3/
```

It runs fine with the original but if I uncomment the last line, the size is reduced to half but shape is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add transformation, not overwrite it.

See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ntzf3/1/

**Code**

```
...    

var rsr = Raphael("canvas", 800, 400);
var elements = rsr.set();

for (var room in floorData) {
    var r = floorData[room];
    var ele = rsr.add([r]);
    elements.push(ele);
    if (r.data) {
        ele.data('room', r.data['room']);
    }
}

elements.forEach(function (el) {
    var e = el[0];
    e.transform(e.transform() + "s0.5,0.5,0,0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It is overwriting the transform information in the original graph. I changed the last line to elements.transform("...s0.5,0.5,0,0") then everything works.